# Destructor gets called when using phoenix construct

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

I'm working on a Boost Spirit Qi project that uses `phoenix::construct` to create an object that has a pointer to another object. I noticed that using `phoenix::construct` calls the destructor at some point (I'm guessing at the end of the function). Why does the destructor get called? How do I get around this?

Note: this isn't my actual code, I made a toy example so it wouldn't be so long

**Objects**

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(int y)
    {
        this->x = y;
    }

    ~Bar()
    {
    }

    int x;
};

class Foo
{
public:

    Foo()
    {
    }

    Foo(Bar* bar) : _bar(bar)
    {
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        delete this->_bar;
    }

    void DoStuff()
    {
        std::cout << this->_bar->x << std::endl;
    }

private:
    Bar *_bar;
};
```

**Grammar**

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct TestGrammar : qi::grammar < Iterator, Foo(), ascii::space_type >
{
    TestGrammar() : TestGrammar::base_type(foo)
    {
        foo = bar[qi::_val = phoenix::construct<Foo>(qi::_1)];
        bar = qi::double_[qi::_val = phoenix::new_<Bar>(qi::_1)];
    }

    qi::rule < Iterator, Foo(), ascii::space_type > foo;
    qi::rule < Iterator, Bar*(), ascii::space_type> bar;
};
```

**Calling Code**

```
std::getline(std::cin, string);

iter = string.begin();
end = string.end();

bool result = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, space, f);

if (result)
{
    State s;
    f.DoStuff();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "No Match!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In `DoStuff` don't forget to `nullptr`-check `_bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor runs on the attribute of the `foo` rule; that is after it has been copied into the referenced attribute.

Since your `Foo` class violates Rule-Of-Three this causes problems. `Foo` should not be copyable (or implement deep copy).

Marking as such:

```
class Foo : public boost::noncopyable {
```

will reveal that the grammar copies the `Foo`:

```
/home/sehe/custom/boost_1_57_0/boost/proto/transform/default.hpp|154 col 9| error: use of deleted function ‘Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)’
```

In short:

1. Write hygienic classes with Rule-Of-Zero or Rule-Of-{Three|Five}
2. Don't do dynamic allocation in Spirit grammars. It'll give you grief.
3. Don't do semantic actions ([Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil))

Here's a quick&dirty fixed version by implementing Rule-Of-Three:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfb17c007bb1c3b0)</kbd>**

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(Bar *bar = 0) : _bar(bar) {}
    Foo(Foo const& o) : _bar(new Bar(*o._bar)) {}
    Foo& operator=(Foo const& o) { 
        Foo tmp;
        tmp._bar = new Bar(*o._bar);
        std::swap(tmp._bar, _bar);
        return *this;
    }

    ~Foo() { delete _bar; }

    void DoStuff() { std::cout << _bar->x << std::endl; }

  private:
    Bar *_bar;
};
```

And here's a slightly less quick&dirty using Rule Of Zero:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65e626ece98e8466)</kbd>**

```
struct Foo {
    using PBar = boost::shared_ptr<Bar>;
    Foo(PBar bar = {}) : _bar(bar) {}

    void DoStuff() { std::cout << _bar->x << std::endl; }

private:
    PBar _bar;
};
```

### Full Code

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii   = boost::spirit::ascii;

struct Bar {
    Bar(int y) { this->x = y; }
    ~Bar() {}

    int x;
};

struct Foo {
    using PBar = boost::shared_ptr<Bar>;
    Foo(PBar bar = {}) : _bar(bar) {}

    void DoStuff() { std::cout << _bar->x << std::endl; }

  private:
    PBar _bar;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct TestGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Foo(), ascii::space_type>
{
    TestGrammar() : TestGrammar::base_type(foo)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        foo = bar     [ _val = phoenix::construct<Foo::PBar>(_1) ] ;
        bar = double_ [ _val = phoenix::new_<Bar>(_1)      ] ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, Foo(), ascii::space_type> foo;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Bar*(), ascii::space_type> bar;
};

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    It iter = input.begin();
    It end = input.end();

    TestGrammar<It> grammar;
    Foo f;
    bool result = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, ascii::space, f);

    if (result) {
        //State s;
        f.DoStuff();
    } else {
        std::cout << "No Match!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer (as usual). I still have a decent amount to learn and I appreciate you pointing out a few things to look in to. Spending so much time in the managed world has ruined me haha